# Treebeard admin in Django

Tags: django, django-treebeard

I've setup Treebeard in Django and everything seems to have gone well.
I tried to setup the admin system and I can see my models being presented in the admin interface. 
However, when I try to add new data using the admin interface, I get the following error in my template. The code still works fine, and I did a check in my DB and the data seems to be inserted properly. However, the view doesn't seem to load properly.
Any idea about what is causing this??

The exception am getting is:

> Caught an exception while rendering: Failed lookup for key [request] in u'[{\'action_index\': 0, \'block\': , , , , , , ]>}, {\'block\': , , , ]>, , , , , \n \'>, ]>, , ]>, , , , ]>, , , \n \'>, , , , , , , , , ]>, , ]>, \n \'>]>}, {\'cl\': , \'root_path\': None, \'actions_on_bottom\': False, \'title\': u\'Select album to change\', \'has_add_permission\': True, \'media\': , \'is_popup\': False, \'action_form\': , \'actions_on_top\': True, \'app_label\': \'gallery\'}, {\'MEDIA_URL\': \'\'}, {\'LANGUAGES\': ((\'ar\', \'Arabic\'), (\'bn\', \'Bengali\'), (\'bg\', \'Bulgarian\'), (\'ca\', \'Catalan\'), (\'cs\', \'Czech\'), (\'cy\', \'Welsh\'), (\'da\', \'Danish\'), (\'de\', \'German\'), (\'el\', \'Greek\'), (\'en\', \'English\'), (\'es\', \'Spanish\'), (\'et\', \'Estonian\'), (\'es-ar\', \'Argentinean Spanish\'), (\'eu\', \'Basque\'), (\'fa\', \'Persian\'), (\'fi\', \'Finnish\'), (\'fr\', \'French\'), (\'ga\', \'Irish\'), (\'gl\', \'Galician\'), (\'hu\', \'Hungarian\'), (\'he\', \'Hebrew\'), (\'hi\', \'Hindi\'), (\'hr\', \'Croatian\'), (\'is\', \'Icelandic\'), (\'it\', \'Italian\'), (\'ja\', \'Japanese\'), (\'ka\', \'Georgian\'), (\'ko\', \'Korean\'), (\'km\', \'Khmer\'), (\'kn\', \'Kannada\'), (\'lv\', \'Latvian\'), (\'lt\', \'Lithuanian\'), (\'mk\', \'Macedonian\'), (\'nl\', \'Dutch\'), (\'no\', \'Norwegian\'), (\'pl\', \'Polish\'), (\'pt\', \'Portuguese\'), (\'pt-br\', \'Brazilian Portuguese\'), (\'ro\', \'Romanian\'), (\'ru\', \'Russian\'), (\'sk\', \'Slovak\'), (\'sl\', \'Slovenian\'), (\'sr\', \'Serbian\'), (\'sv\', \'Swedish\'), (\'ta\', \'Tamil\'), (\'te\', \'Telugu\'), (\'th\', \'Thai\'), (\'tr\', \'Turkish\'), (\'uk\', \'Ukrainian\'), (\'zh-cn\', \'Simplified Chinese\'), (\'zh-tw\', \'Traditional Chinese\')), \'LANGUAGE_BIDI\': False, \'LANGUAGE_CODE\': \'en-us\'}, {}, {\'perms\': , \'messages\': [], \'user\': }, {}]'

This happens after I hit the save button in Django admin.

This is my admin.py implementation:

```
class MP_Album_Admin(TreeAdmin):
 pass

admin.site.register(Album,MP_Album_Admin)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. It's not sufficient adding 'django.core.context_processors.request' to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS tuple in settings.py.

I added also

```
"django.core.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media"
```

and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add 'django.core.context_processors.request' to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS tuple in settings.py.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to add 'treebeard' application to INSTALLED_APPS.

My settings.py is similar to default one. I always add `PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__ file__))` variable, so my TEMPLATE_DIRS looks like that:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_PATH + '/templates',
)
```